# Brace expansion : run several commands instead of expanding on one line?

Tags: linux, bash, expansion

When you use brace expansion in bash, something like

```
echo {a,b,c}
```

becomes

```
echo a b c
```

Is there a way to expand it to 3 separate commands, one for each expansion, instead?

So that:

```
echo {a,b,c}
```

would become

```
echo a
echo b
echo c
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is this just a "because I wanna know" question, or is there a real use case for it?  We could go through some gymnastics to get it done:

```
$ eval echo\ {a,b,c}\;
a
b
c
```

But I'd hunt down anyone that was putting in these kinds of obfuscatory commands into our system scripts.

Why not go for clarity instead:

```
$ for X in {a,b,c}; do echo $X; done
```

You could even go whole-hog and put in a couple of newlines and indent it a bit so that you'd always be able to understand what you were trying to do.

Comment: @peth - I'm assuming this is a simplified example.  If it is indeed as simple as a list, then you're right.  If it's something more like `file-{r,b,g}{m,n,o}{x,y.z}.foo` then it's better to use the short form than enumerating all 27 value.

Comment: @peth - I thought it was a good follow-up question.

Comment: i've wanted to know this for a long time, thanks ! :)

Comment: Well, the use case was programs that don't accept more than one file (for instance), so where the expansion wouldn't work. Therefore, it'd be nice to be easily able to just run the program multiple times. The `for` works for this, but it's still more typing :P

Comment: I used it to cleanup multiple git branches: `eval git branch -d \{ branch-a, branch-b }\; `

Answer (score 3):

Based on [Mark Mann's selected answer](https://superuser.com/questions/304807/brace-expansion-run-several-commands-instead-of-expanding-on-one-line/304817#304817), I was able to further derive this example, which works great:

```
$ eval echo\ category_{17,32,33}.properties\{,.bak\}\;
category_17.properties category_17.properties.bak
category_32.properties category_32.properties.bak
category_33.properties category_33.properties.bak
```

What that is showing, is when you are using multiple occurrences of brace expansion within a line, Mark's original example would have printed every variation individually. Instead, I wanted to use his answer to move/rename multiple files. To ensure that the output matched the format that `mv` normally expects (`mv oldfilename newfilename`), I escaped the second occurrence of brace expansion, so that it wouldn't be evaluated until *after* the initial `eval` command had executed.

As the above output appeared as expected, I was then able to run the following command:

```
$ eval mv\ category_{17,32,33}.properties\{,.bak\}\;
$ ls
category_17.properties.bak  category_32.properties.bak  category_33.properties.bak
```

Many thanks to Mark for his original answer. Please up-vote his answer if you like what his answer allowed me to do :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo {a,b,c} | xargs -n1
a
b
c
```

Comment: Notes: (1) If the command in question was other than `echo`, then we would need to supply it to `xargs` explicitly (e.g. `echo {a,b,c} | xargs -n1 cowsay`). (2) `xargs` interprets quotes and backslashes. The behavior doesn't matter in this simple case, but in general it does. // +1 anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
printf '%s\n'  echo{\ a,\ b,\ c}
```

Comment: eval echo{\ a\;,\ b\;,\ c\;}